# Is it possible to get building data from Google Maps?

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

Is it possible to manipulate or duplicate the building data (`landscape.man_made`) for Google Maps? I've been Googling about building data, but not really turning anything up. I'd like to be able to enhance the existing map to add live shadows (for example). Thanks in advance, obie

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately it's not possible to access the raw data behind the Maps API.